# React.cloneElement not appending className

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I append or change the className prop with React.cloneElement?

When I use React.cloneElement I'm unable to change or append the className prop. I've searched for hours but I found nothing. React.Children.only or removing the spread don't change the behavior. It appear to be a bug, or a performance optimization feature?.

Expect html: `<div class="parent"><div class="child other-class">testing...</div></div>`

Result html: `<div class="parent"><div class="child">testing...</div></div>`

Class example:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={"parent"}>
        {React.cloneElement(React.Children.only(this.props.children), {
          ...this.props.children.props,
          className: `${this.props.children.props.className} other-class`,
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className={"child"}>{"testing..."}</div>;
  }
}
```

Functional component example:

```
const Parent = ({ children }) => (
  <div className={"parent"}>
    {React.cloneElement(React.Children.only(children), {
      ...children.props,
      className: `${children.props.className} other-class`,
    })}
  </div>
);

const Child = () => <div className={"child"}>{"testing..."}</div>;
```

```js
const Parent = ({ children }) => (
  <div className={"parent"}>
    {React.cloneElement(React.Children.only(children), {
      ...children.props,
      className: `${children.props.className} other-class`,
    })}
  </div>
);

const Child = () => <div className={"child"}>{"testing2..."}</div>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Parent>
      <Child />
    </Parent>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hi! Please share an example of using `Parent` and `Child`. For best results, provide a **runnable** example using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: *"It appear to be a bug...?"* In general, as programmers, if the behavior of something well-established and thoroughly-tested isn't what we expect, we're much better off assuming that the problem is with **our** code, not the well-established, thoroughly-tested thing. In [The Pragmatic Programmer](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips) the aphroism they use is "`select` is not broken" after a famous(ish) story about someone insisting up down left right and sideways that the basic `select` function in Solaris was broken. It was, of course, his code. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder good point about a working example. I also share your opinion about assumptions but that doesn't solve this problem I'm pondering on for almost a day now. I gladly accept any information proving my lack of knowledge :-)

Comment: Did you see the answer? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're never using `className` in `Child`, which is what you're manipulating in `Parent`. `Child` puts a `className` on a `div`, but that isn't **`Child`**'s `className`, it's just a hardcoded one that `Child` puts on the `div`.

If you want `Child` to put that class on the `div`, you have to write the code to do that. Also, you don't need the spread, the props are merged. Finally, to get the original `className`, I'd use the result of calling `Children.only`, rather than going back to `this.props.children` (though that will work because `only` would throw if there weren't only one).

See comments:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        // Get the `className` from the child after verifying there's only one
        const child = React.Children.only(this.props.children);
        const className = `${child.props.className} other-class`;
        return (
            <div className={"parent"}>
                {React.cloneElement(child, {
                    // No need to spread previous props here
                    className,
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
        // Use `className` from `Child`'s props
        const className = (this.props.className || "") + " child";
        return <div className={className}>{"testing..."}</div>;
    }
}

// Note the `classname` on `Child`, to show that your code using
// `this.props.children.props.className`
ReactDOM.render(<Parent><Child className="original"/></Parent>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.child {
    color: red;
}
.child.other-class {
    color: green;
}
.original {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```